# Logging in react-native using winston

Tags: react-native, winston

I am trying to use winston in my react-native app for logging errors and other things in runtime. But after installing winston it gives me following error

```
`Unable to resolve module crypto
 Unable to resolve module cycle
 Unable to resolve module fs`
```

Is winston even compatible with react-native?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

So, I found out that winston is not supported in react native. So, now i have implemented a customised logging system.

Answered this so that no one wastes their time with winston if working on react native

Comment: any chance your solution is open source? :)

Comment: its not a library or anything, i created an api in python which receives the error log and saves in aws elastic cache.